# Android scroll further than recyclerview

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

My current layout file is as follows below. The ImageButton adds a new entry to the recyclerview. The problem is that when the recyclerview has 6 entries, all space is absorbed by it and the ImageButton gets below the screen and cannot be scrolled to see it.

Here is the result with 5 items

[image: 5 Items in recyclerview]

and here's the result after pressing the plus button

[image: 6 items in recyclerview]

As you can see, the plus button has disappeared below the screen. What's the best way to allow the user to scroll to make it visible? Because scrolling now doens't work.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".AddWheelActivity"
    android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
        android:layout_margin="15dp"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/greeny">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_title_text"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                />
            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
                android:textSize="35dp"
                android:lines="1"
                android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>
        </LinearLayout>
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"

        android:layout_margin="15dp">

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:orientation="vertical">

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="@string/add_option_text"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"
                android:textAlignment="center"
                android:textSize="20dp"
                />

            <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/options_recyclerView"
                android:orientation="vertical">
            </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
            <ImageButton
                android:id="@+id/button_add_option"
                android:layout_width="30dp"
                android:layout_height="30dp"
                android:src="@drawable/icon_plus"
                android:scaleType="centerCrop"
                android:background="@null"
                android:layout_gravity="right"
                android:layout_margin="15dp"/>

        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Put `ScrollView` from the parent layout of your recyclerview.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**simple solution edit your xml file as following and don't forget to accept answer if it work ;)**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".AddWheelActivity"
android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
android:orientation="vertical">

<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:cardCornerRadius="5dp"
    android:layout_margin="15dp"
    android:backgroundTint="@color/greeny">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_title_text"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />
        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="15dp"
            android:textSize="35dp"
            android:lines="1"
            android:inputType="textCapSentences"/>
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:layout_margin="15dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/add_option_text"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:textSize="20dp"
            />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/options_recyclerView"
            android:orientation="vertical">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>

    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
            <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/button_add_option"
            android:layout_width="30dp"
            android:layout_height="30dp"
            android:src="@drawable/icon_plus"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:background="@null"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_margin="15dp"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Best practice in such cases is to make the Image button sticky/floating, the user shouldn't have to scroll to the bottom of the view to add new item. If you still want to put it at the bottom of your recycler view then you wrap it inside a scroll view or make it as the last item of ur recycler view.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use ScrollView

```
<ScrollView
android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
android:background="#000000"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:fillViewport="true" <!-- here -->
android:layout_height="match_parent" >

...

</ScrollView>
```

[look here](https://www.tutlane.com/tutorial/android/android-scrollview-horizontal-vertical-with-examples)

Answer (score 0):

Use `NestedScrollView`

Do something like this:

```
<androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        ... other elements

        <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />

    </androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
</androidx.core.widget.NestedScrollView>
```